# The requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system while installing CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have PHP version 7, Windows 10 Pro OS, and have already injected `extension=php_intl.dll` in php.ini without the comment. (It doesn't even have `;extension=php_intl.dll` in the first place)

Installing via composer shows the following error:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

```
- cakephp/cakephp 3.6.9 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.6.8 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.6.7 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.6.6 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.6.5 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.6.4 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.6.3 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.6.2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.6.10 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.6.1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.6.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- Installation request for cakephp/cakephp 3.6.* -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.6.0, 3.6.1, 3.6.10, 3.6.2, 3.6.3, 3.6.4, 3.6.5, 3.6.6, 3.6.7, 3.6.8, 3.6.9].
```

Comment: Please specify your operating system.

Comment: So what is your problem? Reading the error message? Read it and act accordingly. Using Google was obviously not your first choice either. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sehdev: Windows 10 Pro

Answer (score 0):

In your `php.ini` file, uncomment the following line

```
;extension=php_intl.dll
```